# C# Win.Form - graphics disappear after load

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, user-controls, drawing

I'm drawing on a User Control to show the time between two dates. My problem is when the applications starts running or every time I Refresh() the User Control all graphics disappears until the Form is resized.

Observing how the Form behaves when it refreshes, the User Control is shown on the screen for a few frames before it disappears.

I hope you can help me solve this mystery as I am clueless of the problem.

Best Regards,
Mathias

PS: Here is my code for the user control:

```
public partial class CalendarView : UserControl
{
    [Category("Behavior")]
    //these reads the start and end date for the datastrip from the parent form
    public DateTime StartDateTime (...)
    public DateTime EndDateTime (...)
    public int Space
    {
        get
        {
            double totalDays = (EndDateTime - StartDateTime).TotalDays;
            if (totalDays == 0) { totalDays = 1; }
            return (int)(GraphicsWidth / totalDays);
        }
    }
    private int GraphicsWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return panelDateTimeStrip.Width - 2;
        }
    }

    public CalendarView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void drawDates()
    {
        Pen darkGray = new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDarkDark);
        Pen lightGray = new Pen(Color.LightGray);
        Pen gray = new Pen(Color.Gray);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlDarkDark);
        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        int graphicsHeight = panelDateTimeStrip.Height - 2;
        Graphics graphics = panelDateTimeStrip.CreateGraphics();

        //<-----drawing all graphics------>\\

        graphics.Dispose();
        darkGray.Dispose();
        lightGray.Dispose();
        gray.Dispose();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        drawDates();
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    private void CalendarView_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void CalendarView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawDates();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps moving the call to base.OnPaint before the call to drawDates could help (and use the Graphics object passed in the PaintEventArgs)

Comment: You should pretty much never use `CreateGraphics`, use `e.Graphics` from the PaintEventArgs as @steve says.

Comment: You should not `Dispose()` until you leave.
The Dispose aims to releases all resources used by the Graphics
`private void CalendarView_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Dispose here
}`

Comment: You can f.e. pass the e.Graphics in the OnPaint Method to the draw Method where you can then use e.Graphics.DrawString(...) or sth. as addition to @Blorgbeard comment. And the Dispose() releases the objects directly as LeMara mentioned, so the garbage Collector cleans them up to early and they directly disappear.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who helped me. I have explained a mistake I found myself in a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments pretty much answer this, but since no-one has posted an answer yet, here's how you should change your code:

```
private void drawDates(Graphics graphics)
{
    // create pens and brushes
    // do not CreateGraphics, use the parameter instead

    //<-----drawing all graphics------>\\

    // dispose pens and brushes; do not dispose graphics!
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);    
    drawDates(e.Graphics);
}
```

Notice that you call `base.OnPaint` before doing your own drawing, and you don't use `CreateGraphics` anymore.

Comment: After implementing this solution, all my graphics disappeared! I found out that my onPaint method was drawing onto another panel (**Graphics graphics = panelDateTimeStrip.CreateGraphics();**), which was bad. So I have created a new object using the above code, and it both works better and looks better. Thanks! (Y)